# In what order is Event delivered to Widgets and its Children in SWT

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

Say I have a Panel which contains a button.  I added a DragMove listener to the Panel so I can drag-move the panel in any part of it.  However I do not want the same behavior when I press down the button.  Is there a way to do that?

In Qt there the event delivery hierarchy is clear and you can stop the event being processed further in any layer you want.  But I could not seem to find similar mechanism for SWT.  Does a graceful solution exists for this?

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event hierarchy in SWT. An event is delivered to the widget that registered a listener for it.

The snippet below illustrates this:

```java
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Listener listener = new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
      System.out.println( event );
    }
  };
  Display display = new Display();
  Shell shell = new Shell( display );
  shell.setText( "Shell" );
  shell.addListener( SWT.MouseDown, listener );
  Button button = new Button( shell, SWT.PUSH );
  button.setText( "Button" );
  button.setBounds( 100, 100, 400, 100 );
  button.addListener( SWT.MouseDown, listener );
  shell.setSize( 600, 600 );
  shell.open();
  while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
    if( !display.readAndDispatch() )
      display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
}
```

It places a button within a parent widget (a `Shell` in this case). The mouse down event is delivered to the button (and only to the buton) if it occured within the bounding recangle of the button. Mouse down events that occur outside of the button are delivered to the Shell.

SWT has *display filters* to listen to **all** events of a certain type. Events are first delivered to the display filters and then passed on to the specific widget if none o the filters vetoed.

If you would add a mouse-down listener to the `Display` it would get notified for all mouse-down events and could also veto the event by setting the `doit` field of the event to `false`.

```java
Display display = new Display();
Listener filter = new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    if( /* condition */ ) {
      event.doit = false;
    }
  }
};
display.addFilter( SWT.MouseDown, filter );
```

Please let us know if you have a specific use case that you think would require an event hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.  So Display listeners always get Events before specific widgets?

Comment: Yes, events are first delivered to the Display filter(s) and then passed on to the specific widget if none of the filters vetoed.